# rsync --chown works for group, but not owner

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to push data from one server to another using rsync. I need to set the owner and permissions on the remote server. Here is my rsync:

```
rsync --chown=process:sambausers --chmod=D770,F770 -rptlvog /home/cloudserv/test.txt cloudserv@xx.xx.xx.xx:/Drive_D/docs/temp
```

All works, except the owner is not set - owner is set to cloudserv, which is the user rsync is sshing as.
Can anyone tell me what I am misisng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not root on the server, so you can't change the owner. You need to connect with root@xx.xx.xx.xx

Comment: ahh. You are correct. I tried running the command as root - same result. So, I am assuming the chown is done by the connecting user?

Comment: Of course ! It change the owner on the server. So you need to be root on the ssh connection to be able to change the owner on the server